# How do I properly package applications with rubygems?

Tags: ruby, dependencies, rubygems, distribution

I've been working on some utilities (not libraries) that I'd like to share. What is the proper way to use rubygems to package them? Are there any best practices?

Specifically, I'd like to know how to deal with the possibility of the user having multiple versions of a dependency. Bundler does an excellent job in a development environment; is there any equivalent for end-user applications? Any way to use the `gemspec` to automatically require the correct version of all specified gems?

I'm aware of several *package-everything-as-executable* solutions, but I'd like to avoid them. I think the user should be able to issue `gem install my_utility` and get the latest version with the correct dependencies and still have a sane environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your biggest question is how to get the correct version of a gem dependency when using a gemspec file, am I right?

Well, here's an example of the typical gemspec file:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = "hello_world"
  spec.version      = "0.1.0"
  spec.author       = "Bilbo Baggins"
  # Here's a gem dependency
  spec.add_dependency "json", ">= 0.4.0"
end
```

If you wanted to use **only** the json version 1.5.4, try this sort of thing:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  # ...
  spec.add_dependency "json", "= 0.4.0"
end
```

This will only make sure that the specified version is installed already, but to actually make sure you *load* that in your utility, you can do this:

```
gem "json", "= 0.4.0"
require "json"
```

Comment: In my code, I use the standard `require` to load libraries. Will only the `gemspec` suffice to make sure the specified version is required, even if the user has multiple, possibly newer versions of the gem? As a developer, I deal with this issue using RVM gemsets, but I wouldn't like to impose that on other people.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I meant, but it seems it isn't actually true... But good news: there is still a way to do this easily! I'll update the answer right now.

Comment: +1, thanks. I was under the impression the `gem` method was there to replace `require`, so I avoided it because it would result in tight coupling with rubygems. I'm trying to work out a good place in which to isolate these calls. Just to clarify, it won't exactly _load_ my libraries, only ensure the correct versions are loaded when they are `require`d, right?

Comment: Sure, no prob! :) And yeah, the only thing they do is to tell require which version of a gem to load. I have no idea how, though, haha

Comment: Well then I guess I'm set. Accepted your answer. Thanks again for clearing this up!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/rubygems.html) for developing gems.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to have people `bundle exec` my app. I need a way to lock the gem versions during load time.

Comment: gem users don't need to use bundler. bundler rubygems interface for gemspec and  dependency otomation and gem versioning.